# Delete All Products (and their variants)

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, products, delete

I'm looking for the correct way to delete all of the products and related variants from my Commerce site. This is just for my local development environment as I'm debugging an import job. The delete() function is the wrong code in the following console controller:

```
public function actionNuke()
{
    $products = Product::findAll();
    foreach($products as $product){
        $product->delete();
    }
    $this->stdout("Deleted All Products", Console::FG_GREEN);
    return ExitCode::OK;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
\Craft::$app->getElements()->deleteElement($product);
```

Then run garbage collection.

Comment: Ran the command `php craft gc --delete-all-trashed=1` afterwards for the garbage collection. Works great, thanks!